# How to draw rectangle in negative quadrant in windows forms c#

Tags: c#, graphics, system.drawing

I want to draw the rectangle in negative quadrant (left and top side of the origin point)... any help please

Answer (score 1):

Just use negative numbers for the X and Y positions.

```
Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, -100, -100, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle original = new Rectangle(10,10,50,50);
Rectangle negative = new Rectangle(original.Location.X - (original.Width * 2), original.Location.Y - (original.Height * 2), original.Width, original.Height);
```